# Arch / Eclipse / C++ / Where to place libraries?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, archlinux

I'm trying my hand at C++, I've got Eclipse on my Arch machine.  I'm trying to get an example at [Boost.Org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1/src.html) working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_context io;

  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  t.wait();

  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I've downloaded the library tar and extracted it to /usr/local/include as this appeared the most obvious from the default include folders, but I still got the following error: `Unresolved inclusion: <boost/asio.hpp>`

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Just needed to give Eclipse time to acknowledge the library being moved to /usr/local/include (a default include folder).

Comment: I'd be surprised if arch doesn't have boost in the actual package repository (whatever it is that arch uses).  Why not use that directly?

Comment: If you are just starting with C++, chances are you don't want to jump straight away to Boost. Please have a look at this [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list.

Comment: Have you tried googling "eclipse configure library include paths"?  You can point your IDE at the place you decided it made sense to install your libraries, rather than groping around for places the IDE might already search.

Comment: I like to do things manually, to help me understand what is going on.  I'm looking at Boost because my current goal is to create an app/service that can communicate with instances of itself on other machines on the network.  Saw that Boost was advised as a good library for this.

Comment: @TonyDelroy as I said, I extracted the library to the /usr/local/include folder which was one of the default include folders.

Comment: Boost::asio's pretty good for that. Some docs on adding header search locations to eclipse: https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm . Found by googling: add include folder to eclipse

Comment: Is this a compilation error or eclipse error?

Comment: Looks like Eclipse was just taking its time, as it's now lost the error on the #include.  Thank you everyone for your input!

Comment: If I remember correctly ASIO is one of the Boost packages that requires some special care and feeding to build. You're probably not out of the water just yet.

Comment: Nothing in your answer or comments above says `/usr/local/include` was a default include path *for Eclipse*.  You only say it's an obvious place to install to.  I'm suggesting you check Eclipse configuration to make sure it's actually looking in `/usr/local/include`.  Anyway, good to hear it was.  May be worth updating your question with "UPDATE: I just had to wait for Eclipse to notice boost..." and list the manual triggering VTT mentions below, as that may help future readers.

Comment: You may need to manually trigger reindexing of header files by opening context menu for project -> Index -> Rebuild. Also note that eclipse indexer is rather glitchy and does not support even some pre C++11 code. So you may have a rather hard time utilizing boost libraries.

Comment: @VTT Oooh, thanks, didn't see that option. I was going with 'PROJECT / REFRESH'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just run

```
pacman -S boost
```

this will install boost in the system include path that GCC always uses.

Comment: I'll accept this when possible, even thought the issue has been resolved and it isn't what I'll use, as it may prove useful to someone else.

Comment: in any case, you're in for a world of pain with Eclipse for C++. It's a sub-par experience unless you already know the IDE very well and aren't willing to learn another more suited to C++ dev.

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: Qt Creator with the clang code model is quite powerful ; it's one of the only IDEs to have a real semantic understanding of the code through a compiler.

Comment: What build system would you recomend, there's qmake, CMake, Qbs available?

Comment: the most used in the modern c++ ecosystem is cmake.